# Adding new keys to a server that doesn't accept password login

Tags: ssh, key-exchange, windows-10

I have a Raspberry Pi with some projects on it. It is open to the internet at port 22. I have fail2ban installed and I have disabled password log in. Right now I have successfully set up a key pair between the Pi and a Windows laptop.

Now that I cannot log into the Pi without a key, scp won't let me send a new key from my desktop. I'm assuming that I have to transfer the public (desktop) key to the laptop, then to the Pi. Is there a preferred or streamlined way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up an ssh-proxy tunnel on the authorized Laptop, opening up a listening port, and connecting it through your ssh tunnel to the PI, then send the file through that, but I'm not sure that is any easier or more streamlined, then just (as you correctly said) copying the file to the laptop, and transferring it from there.

It might save you time in the future if you end up needing to do it multiple times though.